# How can you save 2 HTML SELECT Drop-Down Inputs as Pairs using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 selects drop downs like these
[image]

This is the code:
this is to create the drop down with numbers using jquery

```
$(function(){
var $select = $(".1-100");
for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
}
});
```

this is the html

```
<select id="subject" name="subject">
    <option value="">Choose Subject</option>
    <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
    <option value="Mathematics Literacy">Mathematics Literacy</option>
    <option value="Physical Science">Physical Science</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Life Sciences">Life Sciences</option>
    <option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
    <option value="History">History</option>
    <option value="Life Orientation">Life Orientation</option>
```

I am trying to save the value pairs like or just in a normal javascript array

```
student: {
    subject: {
        value: 'Mathematics',
        key: '75',
    },
    subject: {
        value: 'English',
        key: '88',
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have input element as range for years. I can change value of year by buttons. I would like to create nested list in second select that depends on year from range input and on first select - id countrySelect.

```
<input type="range" id="yearRange" min="0" max="3" list="yearsDatalist" value="3"
onChange="changeYear(value)" onInput="changeYearLite(value)">
    <datalist id="yearsDatalist">
        <option value="0" label="1918"></option>
        <option value="1" label="1936"></option>
        <option value="2" label="1950"></option>
        <option value="3" label="1981"></option>
    </datalist>
```

Then I have two select elements. The first one is static - not necessary to change the values there:

```
<select id="countrySelect">
    <option value="0">Sweden</option>
    <option value="1">Germany</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
</select>
```

Second select is dependent on year and on values in first select with id=countrySelect

```
<select id="itemSelection"></select>
```

I used object for values like this in some different project:

const yearsFilterDataList = {
"1918": {
"0": "Choose model",
"volvo": "Volvo",
"mercedes": "Mercedes",
"saab": "Saab"
}, ...

**here's something similar I made a few years back, check it out.**